# Determine for which values of some parameters a stochastic integral is a Brownian motion

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Let $W_t$ be a Brownian motion on $(\Omega, F, (F_t)_t, P)$. Find all values of $a$ and $b$ such that the stochastic integral $$X_t=\int_0^t a+\frac{bu}{t} \;dW_u$$ is a Brownian motion.

1)So I need to check that $X_0=0$ almost surely, and since here we have $t$ in the denominator I need to show that the limit of $X_t$ when $t$ approaches $0$ is $0$ a.s. If $b=0$ then it is fine. If $b\neq 0$  this leads to prove  that $\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{1}{t}\int_0^tu \:dW_u =0$ since I can write $X_t=aW_t+\frac{b}{t}\int_0^tu \:dW_u$. Now since $u$ is smooth the stochastic integral reduces to the Riemann-Stiltjes integral
$$ \frac{1}{t}\int_0^tu \:dW_u =W_t- \frac{1}{t}\int_0^t W_u du$$, therefore since almost every trajectory of $W_t$ is continuous the limit is zero almost everywhere.

2) Now the increments $X_{t+h}-X_t=\int_t^{t+h}(a-\frac{bu}{t+h})dW_u-b\int_0^t\frac{hu}{t(t+h)}dW_u$, so if I want this to be independent of $F_t$ then $b$ must be zero, otherwise the second integral is measurable w.r.t $F_t$. (I'm not sure if this is a valid/ correct explanation). If so, then $X_t=aW_t$, so it is a Brownian motion iff $a^2=1$ (because iff in this case the increments have the correct normal distribution). 
If the observation in point is correct I guess I wouldn't need my discussion of point 1, but I'm not sure and I would like some feedback on how i proved that point anyway.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can also check Levy's characterization. If $M$ is a local martingale such that $\langle M\rangle_t = t$ and $M_0=0$ then $M$ is a brownian motion. In your case $\langle X \rangle_t= \int_0^t(a+ b u/t)^2\, du$.

Comment: Ok, this is more advanced than what I studied so far. But computing that integral I get a different condition, namely $a^2+ab+b^3/3=1$, so probably  I have a mistake in my previous reasoning...

Comment: yup, in the increment formula, I think you missed the fact that $X_t=\int f(t,s)\,dWs$ and $X_{t+h}=\int f(t+h,s)\,dWs$. I think it would be easier to calculate the covariance function (and Kolmogorov's theorem for Gaussian processes).

Comment: Hint: Itô's formula yields $$dX_t=(a+b)dW_t+Y_tdt,\qquad Y_t=\frac{b}{t^2}\int_0^tW_udu.$$ The bounded variation part $Y_t$ must be zero hence $b=0$ and the Brownian part must be $dB_t$ for some Brownian motion $B$ hence $(a+b)^2=1$. Thus the solutions $(a,b)$ are...

Comment: So this agrees with the solution I previously found. Was my argument correct/precise? And what about the result yelded by Levy's characterization, why is that different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Levy's characterisation and the use of It$ô$'s lemma give the same answer. I think the independence argument in your approach is not quite enough to conclude that $b$ must be zero, unfortunately (please see my comment below).

**Levy's Characterisation:** The aim here is to show that there is a choice of $a$ and $b$ such that $X_t=\int_{0}^{t}(a+b\frac{u}{t})\text dW_u$ is a martingale with $X_0=0$ and with quadratic variation $\langle X\rangle_t=t$. Now, as you note,
$$
X_t = a\int_{0}^{t}\text dW_u + b\left(W_t-\frac{1}{t}\int_0^{t}W_u~\text du\right) = (a+b)\int_{0}^{t}\text dW_u -\frac{b}{t}\int_0^{t}W_u~\text du \tag{1}
$$
From $(1)$ it is immediate that the choice $b=0$ guarantees both $X_0=0$ and $X_t$ being a martingale. Furthermore, we now see that we require
$(a+b)^2t = \langle X \rangle_t = t$, so that $a=\pm 1$.

**It$\bf ô$'s Lemma:** Identical to the previous argument, but just in terms of the SDE for $(1)$.
$$
\text dX_t = (a + b)~\text dW_t +\frac{b}{t}\left(\frac{1}{t}\int_0^{t}W_u~\text du-W_t\right)\text dt \tag{2}
$$

---

**Your approach:** Your argument in $(1)$ is good. If your argument using independence was true, we should be able to come to it in the following way. Given that $X_{t+h}-X_t$ and $X_t$ are jointly normal, thier independence follows *if, and only if,* we make a choice of $a$ and $b$ that guarantees $\mathbb Cov(X_{t+h}-X_t,X_t)=0$. The independent increments property of $W_t$ implies we want
$$
\mathbb Cov(X_{t+h}-X_t,X_t) = -\frac{tbh}{t+h}\left(\frac{a}{2}+\frac{b}{3}\right) = 0
$$
from which we see $b= -\frac{3}{2}a, 0$ are both valid choices. Consequently, we need more to conclude.

Comment: @bibo, You are welcome.

Comment: @bibo, :) Oh, and, if you are interested, here are a few more tips: i) Smoothness of $u$ in your argument (1) is rather strong. You can get the same job done by noting that $u$ is bounded and increasing on every interval $[0,t]$; this justifies the form of the expression  with the Riemann integral as a direct consequence of the semi-martingale integration by parts formula. ii) You could also mention, in passing, that the almost sure continuity of $W_t$ implies $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{1}{t}\int_{0}^{t}W_u~du=0$ by the fundamental theorem of calculus.